# Problemas con tkinter y sockets en python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, socket

vengo por su ayuda. Sucede que estoy haciendo un juego en python un "Battleship". Cree la interfaz con tkinter y para que sea online comencé a utilizar sockets. El problema es que cuando deseo realizar un "ataque", se pega todo. Se crea bien la conexión, pero al momento de presionar un botón en la cuadrícula de 10x10 donde cada botón tiene la función "atacar()", muere.

```
def crearConexion(host, puerto, nombreJugador, ventanaLogin):  #Funcion encargada de crear la conexion con el cliente
    global sock
    global nombreJugador1

    nombreServidor = str(host.get())
    puerto = int(puerto.get())
    nombreJugador1 = str(nombreJugador.get())
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', puerto))
        sock.listen(1)
        ventanaLogin.destroy()

    except:
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Error","Puerto utilizado o puerto incorrecto, ingrese otro por favor.")

def jugar(matrizEnemigo):
    global Turno

    enviarMensaje(str(matrizEnemigo))

    if Turno == "Jugador 1":
        ataqueEnemigo = recibirMensaje()
        recibirAtaque(ataqueEnemigo)
        Turno = "Jugador 2"
    print "Turno: ", Turno

def atacar(ventanaTableroJuego, posicion):
    global matrizEnemigo
    global matrizBotones
    global Turno
    if Turno == "Jugador 2":
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                if matrizEnemigo[i][j] == "1" or matrizEnemigo[i][j] == "2" or matrizEnemigo[i][j] == "3" or matrizEnemigo[i][j] == "4" or matrizEnemigo[i][j] == "5":
                    matrizEnemigo[i][j] = "X"
                    matrizBotones[posicion].config(bg="black")   
        Turno = "Jugador 1"
        jugar(matrizEnemigo)

def TableroJuego():
    global matrizBotones2
    global matrizBotones
    matrizBotones = []
    matrizCoordenadas = [0] * 20
    fila = 1
    columna = 1
    letra = ""
    k= 10
    l = 0

    ventanaTableroJuego = Tk()
    ventanaTableroJuego.resizable(0,0)
    ventanaTableroJuego.title("Battleship Servidor")
    framePadre = Frame(ventanaTableroJuego)
    framePadre.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky= W)
    framePadre.config(bg= "cyan4")

    for j in range(10):

        if j == 0:
              matrizCoordenadas[0] = Button(framePadre,text="+",width=6,height=3)
              matrizCoordenadas[0].grid(row= 0,column= 0)
              matrizCoordenadas[0].config(bg="cyan4", fg="white")

        if j == 0:
            letra = "A"
        elif j == 1:
            letra = "B"
        elif j == 2:
            letra = "C"
        elif j == 3 :
            letra = "D"
        elif j == 4:
            letra = "E"
        elif j == 5 :
            letra = "F"
        elif j == 6 :
            letra = "G"
        elif j ==  7:
            letra = "H"
        elif j == 8:
            letra = "I"
        elif j == 9:
            letra = "J"

        matrizCoordenadas[j+1] = (Button(framePadre,text=letra,width=6,height=3))
        matrizCoordenadas[j+1].grid(row= 0,column= j+1)
        matrizCoordenadas[j+1].config(bg="cyan3", fg="white")

        matrizCoordenadas[k] = (Button(framePadre,text=j+1,width=6,height=3,bg="white"))
        matrizCoordenadas[k].grid(row= j+1,column= 0)
        matrizCoordenadas[k].config(bg="cyan3", fg="white")
        k+=1

    for i in range(100):
        matrizBotones.append(Button(framePadre,text="",width=6,height=3))
        matrizBotones[i].grid(row= fila,column= columna)
        matrizBotones[i].config(bg="steel blue", command= lambda i=i: atacar(framePadre,i))
        if columna%10==0 and columna != 1:
            fila+=1
            columna = 1
        else:
            columna+=1

    matrizBotones2 = []
    matrizCoordenadas2 = [0] * 20
    fila = 1
    columna = 1
    k= 10
    l = 0

    frameBarcos = Frame(framePadre)
    frameBarcos.grid(row = 1 , column = 11, rowspan= 5, sticky = W, padx=10)

    for i in range(100):
        matrizBotones2.append(Button(frameBarcos,text="",width=2,height=1))
        matrizBotones2[i].grid(row= fila,column= columna)
        matrizBotones2[i].config(bg="steel blue")
        if columna%10==0 and columna != 1:
            fila+=1
            columna = 1
        else:
            columna+=1

    for posicion in barco1tablero:
        matrizBotones2[posicion].config(bg="red")

    for posicion in barco2tablero:
        matrizBotones2[posicion].config(bg="yellow2")

    for posicion in barco3tablero:
        matrizBotones2[posicion].config(bg="magenta4")

    for posicion in barco4tablero:
        matrizBotones2[posicion].config(bg="darkorange")

    for posicion in barco5tablero:
        matrizBotones2[posicion].config(bg="green2")

    Label(framePadre, text="Barcos Propios", bg="cyan3",fg = "white", bd= 5, relief = RAISED, font= "Helvetica 11 bold italic").grid(row = 0, column=11, rowspan=1)

    Button(framePadre, text="Quien parte", bg="red", fg="white", command= lambda: botonQuienParte()).grid(row=7, column=11)

    ventanaTableroJuego.mainloop()
```

El juego tiene tanto un cliente como un servidor, pero con ambos ocurre lo mismo. Por favor, ojalá me puedan ayudar.

Comment: muestra más código, por favor

Comment: @eyllanesc ahí agregué más, espero sea suficiente. Gracias por responder

Comment: Deberías ser más específico con lo que ocurre cuando dices que "muere". ¿Se genera alguna excepción? En caso afirmativo ¿cuál es el mensaje de error? Si no ¿en qué sentido "muere"? ¿la interfaz deja de atender eventos? ¿El servidor recibe algo?